# Server Error in '/' Application - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net-assembly

Can any body please tell me what might be wrong here and how I may go about fixing it?
Thanks

> Could not load file or assembly 'FrameProcessor_dll' or one of its
> dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
> format.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file
> or assembly 'FrameProcessor_dll' or one of its dependencies. An
> attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
> determine why the assembly 'FrameProcessor_dll' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = FrameProcessor_dll  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information was
> supplied for an assembly: WRN: Assembly Name: FrameProcessor_dll |
> Domain ID: 2 WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly
> display name is provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading
> an incorrect assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully
> specified textual identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the
> simple name, version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See
> whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more
> information and common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
> file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/Syncre/Syncre/SyncreWebServices/Syncre_LayerAB_WebService/
> LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Syncre\Syncre\SyncreWebServices\Syncre_LayerAB_WebService\bin
> Calling assembly : (Unknown).
> === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Syncre\Syncre\SyncreWebServices\Syncre_LayerAB_WebService\web.config
> LOG: Using host configuration file:
> C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG:
> Using machine configuration file from
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
> LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
> custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
> download of new URL
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
> ASP.NET Files/root/90b7448e/a25f12e1/FrameProcessor_dll.DLL. LOG:
> Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
> ASP.NET
> Files/root/90b7448e/a25f12e1/FrameProcessor_dll/FrameProcessor_dll.DLL.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/Syncre/Syncre/SyncreWebServices/Syncre_LayerAB_WebService/bin/FrameProcessor_dll.DLL.
> ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing
> terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'FrameProcessor_dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made
> to load a program with an incorrect format.]
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
> codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
> throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
> suppressSecurityChecks) +0
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
> codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
> throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
> suppressSecurityChecks) +34
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
> assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
> throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
> suppressSecurityChecks) +152
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
> Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
> pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
> Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
> forIntrospection) +16    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
> assemblyString) +28
> System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
> assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'FrameProcessor_dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made
> to load a program with an incorrect format.]
> System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
> assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +736
> System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
> +217    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
> ai) +130
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
> compConfig) +170
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
> +91    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
> preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +284
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
> System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
> appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
> configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
> PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
> 'FrameProcessor_dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made
> to load a program with an incorrect format.]
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9955652
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
> +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
> wr, HttpContext context) +254

[image: Dependency Walker reveals that DLLs are intact.]

Dependency Walker reveals that DLLS are intact.

Answer (score 0):

check your IIS and ASP.NET set-up, and make sure that everything is running on target .net version. Check your application pool configuration too. It's not completely clear to detect the problem.

Also it may be fixed by Trying to clean Debug and Release folders in your solution.